# Import react component only if it exists?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, es6-module-loader

I have a directory structure like this:

```
index.js
generated/
|___comp1/Comp1.jsx
|___comp2/Comp2.jsx
|___comp3/Comp3.jsx
|___...
```

- `index.js` is the entry point for webpack.
- The amount of components in `generated/` is uncertain and may vary from build to build.

Does anybody know how I could import and render every component that exists under `generated/` inside `index.js`?

Comment: Is there a maximum to how many there are?

Comment: I think it won't be more than a hundred. :)

Comment: So you're using ES6 imports? I don't think that's possible, but with Node.js you can do a try/catch

Comment: Yes I use imports, but I could use `require` as well I think. Do you mean `try { import ... ` ?

Comment: `import` is base level, but `require` is async, allowing try/catch

Comment: I think Andrew means that client side import statements are handled by a compile step (webpack in your case) rather than during runtime, so there is no way at runtime to tell if they exist or not.